# Which one is correct "Rode" or Has ridden"?

Tags: grammar

He rode a bicycle to work every day last month.
OR
He has ridden a bicycle to work every day last month.

Comment: Either can be correct, depending on what your [reference time](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/21847/16052) is.

Comment: Thanks Timlymington. So I think it should be "I rode a bicycle to work every day last month" and "He has ridden a bicycle to work every day last month".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that 'last month' signals a now concluded time interval, so

> *He has ridden a bicycle to work every day last month / last year / when he was 10.

are not available.

You *can* say

> He has ridden a bicycle to work every day for the last four weeks / this last month.